# Research on graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I am interested in graph theory. My background is mainly algebraic. I have been researching algebraic geometry for five years so I assume that the transition to the graph theory realm shouldn't be so hard. I would like to ask you for a royal path to study advanced graph theory on my own and get a grasp of what are the problems that people are interested in nowadays. I know that this question is broad and general, so any help or advice would be welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why the downvote? There have been similar, well-received, questions at MO.

Comment: Since you have a background in algebra, you can perhaps read the nice little book "Algebraic graph-theory" by Biggs. A lot of algebraic background is for example useful in expander-graphs. You can perhaps also consider problems in Cayley-graphs or shift to hyperbolic groups (and their Cayley graphs).

Comment: sidorenko's conjecture, ramsey's theorem bounds, triangle removal lemma bounds

Comment: This is an excellent resource: Lovász, László. *Graphs and Geometry*. Vol. 65. American Mathematical Soc., 2019. And there is a PDF version linked from [his Budapest webpage](https://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/).